# DokuWiki Media upload size limits effectless

Tags: php, apache, dokuwiki

With various DokuWiki installations (XAMPP on Windows, Std Ubuntu 14.04 Apache, Bitnami DokuWiki VM) I found the media upload limits completely effectless.

Regardless of my setting for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in `php.ini`, I can upload files of much larger size (e.g. 70MB) through media manager - media manager in fact shows my set limit (e.g. "Upload max. 2 MB per file.")

Any hints on what to look at and/or change to get this fixed?

Comment: Its a guess, but probably media manager sets these limit locally to its script, based on some DokuWiki setting

Comment: Strangely dokuwiki seems to never check the limit explicitly. I would anyway expect it's checked on the client side before even trying to upload... Although there are several layers of control none of them seems to succeed in limiting the size. (ironically often people have the reverse problem of not being able to upload big files...)

Comment: For the time being I helped myself by using LimitRequestBody in apache config to limit the upload size. It is still disturbing that DokuWIki states an upload limit based on some checked variables but turns out not to limit anything. Still I think this should not be the final answer for this issue.

Comment: I, too, wonder how DokuWiki manages to get around the limits. My log says `PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 36063516 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0`. `upload_max_filesize = 2M` is even lower. Still, file gets uploaded just fine.

Comment: Cf. report in [Media upload size limits effectless · Issue #1478 · splitbrain/dokuwiki](https://github.com/splitbrain/dokuwiki/issues/1478)